# namespace & __autoload

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have a file SQL_config.php:

```
namespace database;

class SQL_config
{
    private $_server="localhost";
    private $_user="root";
    private $_password="";

    private static $_singleton;
    private $_connection;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->_connection=mysql_connect($this->_server,$this->_user,$this->_password);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$_singleton))
        {
            self::$_singleton=new SQL_config();
        }

        return self::$_singleton;
    }
}
```

and index.php:

```
//namespace database;
//require_once'SQL_config.php';

 function __autoload($class)
    {  
     // convert namespace to full file path  
    //$class = 'database/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';  
    //require_once($class); 
    require_once  $class . '.php'; 
    }  


$connection=database\SQL_config::getInstance();
```

and doesn't work. Warning: require_once(database\SQL_config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Formular_contact\index.php on line 11. For all version I use it give me error
can't somebody help me?

Comment: Careful using the ampersand in question titles; I only stopped in here because I thought `__autoload` was returning by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(CLASS_DIR, "/path_to_your_classes_to_load/");

require_once CLASS_DIR . str_replace('\\', '/', ltrim($className, '\\')) . '.php';
```

Comment: Don't work.
with:

    namespace database;
    require_once'SQL_config.php';

$connection=SQL_config::getInstance();

working 
but I want to use __autoload() function.

    namespace database;
    define("CLASS_DIR","database");
    
     function __autoload($class)
      {  
         
        require_once  "CLASS_DIR" . str_replace('\\','/',ltrim($class,'\\')).'.php';
     }  
    $connection=SQL_config::getInstance();

give:
Fatal error: Class 'database\SQL_config' not found in C:\wamp\www\Formular_contact\index.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "\" with "/" and add a ".php" to the end of the new class name as it will only get the name without the coma and the extension. And locate the class in the correct folder as shown in the path.

```
function __autoload($className){
    $newClassName= str_replace("\\", "/", $className) .".php";
    require_once($newClassName);
}
```

Make sure that you locate the class file in the correct folders such as

./database/SQL_config.php

If your class is in a folder "classes" Try this instead.

```
function __autoload($className){
    $newClassName = "classes/";
    $newClassName .= str_replace("\\", "/", $className) .".php";
    require_once($newClassName);
}
```

Make sure that you locate the class file in the correct folders such as

./classes/database/SQL_config.php

In the code that you have presented - the location of your class file in file structure is also important.